# Envio e-mail pelo CDOSYSMail

Tags: email, asp, envio-de-email

Tenho um código de envio de *e-mail*, que pego o remetente via *request.form* e coloco dentro de uma variável assim:

```
Dim nome, emailremetente
nome = trim(request.form("name"))
emailremetente = trim(request.form("email"))
```

E nesta linha eu insiro as variáveis:

```
'NOME E E-MAIL DO REMETENTE
objCDOSYSMail.From = nome & "<" & emailremetente & ">"
```

Até aqui tudo bem, entretanto se no formulário eu inserir meu *e-mail* particular (meuemail@hotmail.com) ele não envia, mas se eu inserir meuemail@mesmo-domínio-do-site-que-estou-enviando-email.com.br ele envia.

Ou seja, caso o *e-mail* do remetente for do mesmo domínio que está enviando, ele envia, mas se for de outro domínio ele não envia, porquê e como resolver isso?

Comment: Verifique se seu servidor SMTP está configurado para fazer relay para domínios diferentes

Comment: Um teste simples é você conectar na conta que está enviando o email, pelo browser ou gerenciador de emails, e tentar enviar pra esse seuemail@hotmail.com..

Answer (score 0):

Por motivos de SPAM e outros relacionados à segurança, a maioria dos provedores de hospedagem (talvez TODOS) não envia e-mail via script quando o domínio do remetente for diferente do domínio do site.

Se o domínio do seu site for **meusite.com**, o remetente deve obrigatoriamente ser **@meusite.com**.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente não é recomendável colocar o `from` como qualquer e-mail, e os servidores geralmente permitem apenas e-mails do próprio domínio por questão de SPAM. Mas uma alternativa para isso é o uso do `Reply-To`.

Com esta técnica, você mantém o remetente como um e-mail do seu domínio, e acrescenta o header `reply-to` que faz com que, quem receber o e-mail e tentar responder, o e-mail que será utilizado para a resposta será o indicado pelo `reply-to`.

A utilização seria essa:

```
objCDOSYSMail.ReplyTo = "emailDeResposta@dominio.com"
```